# Difference between single quote (') and apostrophe (’) for SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, escaping

I have an SQLite database in which users can add data through my c# application. I have noticed that when the user enters a quote (') I can escape it in my code `line = line.Replace("'", "''");` but when I do the same with the apostrophe (’), it just insert the diamond with a question mark in it.

What is the difference, and how can I handle this properly?

**EDIT:** I have this issue when reading a file with StreamReader

Comment: USe SQL parameters and you dont have to escape anything

Comment: `’` is a unicode character so must be handled accordingly - i.e. with correct text encodings.  Its not something you need to escape and as suggested use a parameterized query and don't worry about it.

Comment: what if i am reading a file? (SQLiteDataReader)